# Java function only works with one text file

Tags: java, operating-system

I've created a function that allocates a text file into blocks of 8 characters using nodes within linked lists. Code snippet (Scanner b & LinkedList list have been initialized):

```
b = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("files\\A.txt")));
b.useDelimiter("");
String A = null;

while (b.hasNext()) {
    A = null;
    A = b.next();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        A = A.concat(b.next());
    }
    list.Insert(A);
```

The file A.txt reads:

```
You can do anything, but not everything.
```

This function works for my text file A and creates 5 nodes (40 characters total) but it doesn't work for B.txt or C.txt if I were to substitute them in the code.

The file B.txt reads:

```
You must be the change you wish to see in the world.
```

The file C.txt reads:

```
Always forgive your enemies; nothing annoys them so much.
```

Whenever I substitute either B.txt or C.txt, I get these error messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at Main.CreateBlocks(Main.java:82)
    at Main.main(Main.java:64)
```

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Because you are trying to read more characters than there are in the files. B.txt got 52 characters, and your algorithm only works if characters number in files are 8-multiple, e.g 40, like in A.txt. You have to control that.

Comment: Also, you can remove this line "A = null;". It does nothing if after it you do "A = b.next();"

Comment: @RubioRic Thank you! How do I close this question if I've gotten the answer?

Comment: You're welcome. I have posted the comment as answer. You can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are trying to read more characters than there are in the files. B.txt got 52 characters, and your algorithm only works if characters number in files are 8-multiple, e.g 40, like in A.txt. You have to control that